# DaggerTestApplicationComponent not generated missing binding...Unsure about this

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

Android Github repo api calling app using Dagger app build but I'm trying to generated a DaggerTestApplicationComponent  by running assembleAndroidTest and it breaks on me with the following stacktrace

[image]

im tryinng to mirror most of the main classes as test classes but its confusing me reading the stacktrace especially when it builds somewhere I accept I've gone wrong

Please help, advice welcome.

ApplicationComponent-------------------------------

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        ApplicationModule.class,
        ActivityBindingModule.class,
        ServiceModule.class,
        RepoServiceModule.class,


})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(MyApplication myApplication);
}
```

ApplicationModule ------------------------------

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {

    private final Application application;

    ApplicationModule(Application application) {

        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    Context provideApplicationContext() {
        return application;
    }
}
```

ActivityBindingModule-----------------------------

```
@Module(subcomponents = {
        MainActivityComponent.class
})
public abstract class ActivityBindingModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ActivityKey(MainActivity.class)
    abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Activity> provideMainActivityInjector (MainActivityComponent.Builder  builder);



}
```

ServiceModule-------------------------------------

```
@Module(includes = NetworkModule.class)
public abstract class ServiceModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    static Moshi provideMoshi() {
        return new Moshi.Builder()
                .add(AdapterFactory.create())
                .add(new ZoneDateTimeAdapter())
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    static Retrofit provideRetrofit(Moshi moshi, Call.Factory callFactory, @Named("base_url") String baseUrl) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .callFactory(callFactory)
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .build();

    }
}
```

RepoServiceModule -----------------------------

```
@Module
public abstract class RepoServiceModule {


   @Provides
   @Singleton
   static RepoService provideRepoService(Retrofit retrofit) {
       return retrofit.create(RepoService.class);
   }

}
```

I have created some test classes mirroring these (this is where my issues are I think....).

TestApplicationComponent -------------------------

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        ApplicationModule.class,
        TestActivityBindingModule.class,
        TestRepoServiceModule.class,
        ServiceModule.class,
})
public interface TestApplicationComponent extends ApplicationComponent {

}
```

TestActivityBindingModule-------------------------

```
@Module(subcomponents = {
        TestMainActivityComponent.class,
})
public abstract class TestActivityBindingModule {


    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ActivityKey(MainActivity.class)
    abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Activity> bindMainActivityInjector(TestMainActivityComponent.Builder builder);
}
```

TestRepoServiceModule---------------------------

```
@Module
public abstract class TestRepoServiceModule {

    @Binds
    abstract RepoService bindRepoService(TestRepoService repoService);
}
```

Any other classes needed can be provided.

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/BenMohammad/MobD)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error basically says you are trying to inject the

**ScreenNavigator** into the **BaseActivity** but Dagger does not know how to get an instance due to a missing provides method or you miss the **@Inject** annotation for the constructor of **ScreenNavigator**

Comment: great, thanks so much it build and generates the code.